# Apexchart Treemap adding extra right padding

Tags: angular, apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

I have a Treemap implemented using Apexcharts (Angular). When screen pixel size is > 904px, the chart adds some padding (~20px) on the right.

I have been trying so many different configurations but unfortunately this padding is not going away for some reason.

Any help is appriciated.

[image]

Code:

```
this.categoryChartOptions = {
  series: [{
    data: [
      {x: 'New Delhi', y: 150},
      ...
    ]
  }],
  chart: {
    height: 320,
    type: 'treemap',
    foreColor: 'white',
    fontFamily: fontFamily,
    redrawOnParentResize: true,
    redrawOnWindowResize: true,
    parentHeightOffset: 0,
    toolbar: {show: false},
    selection: {enabled: false},
    animations: {enabled: true},
    offsetX: 0,
    offsetY: 0
  },
  legend: {show: false},
  title: {
    text: 'Treemap',
    align: 'center',
    style: {fontWeight: 'normal', fontSize: '12'},
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    style: {fontWeight: 'normal', fontSize: '12'},
    formatter: (text, {value}) => [`${text}`, `$${value}`],
    offsetY: -4,
    dropShadow: {enabled: false}
  },
  grid: {
    show: false,
    padding: {top: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0, left: 0}
  },
  colors: [
    '#3B93A5', ...
  ],
  plotOptions: {
    treemap: {
      distributed: true,
      enableShades: false,
      useFillColorAsStroke: true,
    }
  },
  tooltip: {enabled: false}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this issue: https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/issues/4011

Using this solved my problem:

```
xaxis: {
      show: false,
      labels: {
        show: false,
      },
      axisBorder: {
        show: false,
      },
      axisTicks: {
        show: false,
      },
    },
```

Comment: Please note that the initial version of your post was not an answer and would have been deleted by being flagged to moderators. Thans for editing and turning this into an answer. For the future you might enjoy this info: [answer] and [tour].